# probability of number present in a set

Tags: probability, combinatorics

suppose there are N numbers, a combination of T numbers and M numbers are randomly chosen out of this N numbers. how do I find the probability for atleast one number being present in both the sets of M numbers and T number.

Comment: Read this: [How to ask a homework question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1803/how-to-ask-a-homework-question).

Comment: As a hint, count how many ways there are to choose your $T$ numbers and $M$ numbers.  Rather than finding the probability of at least one number being present in both, try instead to find the probability of *no* numbers being present in both.

Comment: Are the combinations chosen with or without replacement?

Comment: @user with replacements!

Answer (score 0):

I will assume (as claimed in comments) that the numbers in both sets (in fact multisets) are chosen with replacement, i.e. with repetitions being allowed. The probability that the multisets contain no common numbers reads then:
$$
\frac1 {N^{T+M}}\sum_{k=1}^{N-1}\binom Nk D (k,T)(N-k)^M,\tag1
$$
where $\binom Nk $ counts the number of ways to choose $k $ distinct numbers out of $N $, the factor $D (k,T)$ counts all possible combinations containing $T$ numbers from the set of the chosen $k$ ones (with repetitions allowed), where every of $k $ numbers appears at least once, and the last factor counts all possible combinations build of $M$ of the rest $N-k$ numbers.

The function $D (k,T) $ can be computed as
$$
D (k,T)=\sum_{i=0}^k (-1)^i\binom ki (k-i)^T={T\brace k}k!,
$$
where ${T\brace k}$ is the Stirling number of second kind.

The probability in question is then the value complementary to (1).